# Test Regex in the new version of Google Analyitcs

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to track some goals via regex and I'm having trouble getting them to work in the new version of Google Analytics.

I've got goal URLs that look like this:

```
/contact/thank_you?f=contact&s=lead_source_1
/contact/thank_you?f=modal&s=lead_source_2
```

and so on.

On an older version of the site, we were tracking f=contact and f=modal as two separate goals, but now I need to track them as the same goal, so I wrote this regex:

```
/contact/thank_you\?f=(contact|modal)&s=whatever
```

Problem is, the Google documentation states that I can test out this regex in the Top Content section of the report.  The old version of Google Analytics has a Top Content section where if I test this regex it works.

The new version of the Analytics doesn't have Top Content; it's been replaced by Pages, which doesn't appear to support regex.

So my question is how do I test a regex on the new version of Analytics.  I don't mind switching back to the old version to test, but its a pain in the butt to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Pages report.

Next to the search box under the graph, click on `advanced`.

[image]

Include - Page - Matching RegEx - put your regex in the box.

Click Apply.

[image]

Comment: While it works (and is probably the only way to do it) it's still an extra couple of steps to achieve the same functionality as the old version. Why not just keep it the same, Google? x_x